# Ant Design TextArea not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is a form that I am trying to create through ant.design:

```
import { createElement as ce, Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const { TextArea } = Input;

class CommentForm extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      ce(Form, { layout: 'inline' },
        ce(FormItem, {},
          ce(TextArea, {}),
          ce(Button, {
            htmlType: 'submit',
            type: 'primary',
          }, 'Post'),
          )
        )
    );
  }
}

const CommentBubble = Form.create()(CommentForm);

export default CommentBubble;
```

I keep getting the following error when I try to use the `TextArea`:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `CommentForm`.

But I don't get the error if I render an `Input` instead of the `TextArea`.

[Ant Design documentation.](https://ant.design/components/input/)

Comment: Have you tried without createElement ? I dont see any errors in your code ...